# Dissect a square into 3:1 rectangles

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

I am being known for [Geometrical](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58393/is-s-larger-than-the-radius-of-circumscribed-circle) and [Topological](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58369/the-three-utilities-puzzle) Puzzles, So continuing with the trend here is another one.

> Completely dissect a square into the lowest number of different sized
>   rectangles with integer edges and a length to width ratio of 3 to 1.

**EDIT:**

Since people are having a hard time. I will add the solution here. **Let your pointer do the work.**

[image]

Comment: Does the square have to be a particular size?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil No, one that gives the lowest number 3:1 rectangles.

Comment: This can be solved by inspection/intuition.

Comment: Re the edit: I don't see a solution there...?

Comment: @Ankoganit Look deep(deeper.)

Comment: @Ankoganit There's an image posted in the thread. I suspect it's pixel dimensions represent the size of the total square to be divided.

Comment: Not what I would call a "complete" solution. Using that size square and the previous implied maximum of 22 rectangles (and an arbitrary minimum of 6) to limit my search, I get over 180 000 possible sets of rectangles. Luckily I can check them all with one run of my tiling program, which is not optimised for this sort of problem so will take some time.

Comment: I looked at @theonetruepath’s solution, there seems to be absolutely zero chance of finding that without specialized software. Would you care to make another puzzle for us, where we are given the pieces, and need to no-computer a square out of them? The solution looks like it might have just the right complexity for that sort of puzzle.

Comment: @Bass that's why I didn't use a **no-computers** tag. Sure I will work on one.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL do you have a proof that this is optimal, ie it can't be done with fewer than 12 rectangles?

Comment: @theonetruepath I checked it using a program I made.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL understood... but presumably you used some logic as well to limit the search. For example, how did you eliminate candidates like these:10:  2 8 34 44 61 62 75 82 83 95 (342)
10:  2 8 34 44 61 62 75 82 97 100 (357)
10:  2 8 34 44 61 62 76 77 94 99 (351)
10:  2 8 34 44 61 62 76 81 91 95 (348)
10:  2 8 34 44 61 62 76 83 87 97 (348)  I have about 100GB of these in a file, and there are probably another 150GB of candidates with 11 rectangles. And those are just up to size 100. There are arbitrarily many if you allow scaling of rectangles up to arbitrarily large numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the best I found so far with a square size of 96 as given by the image posted by OP as a solution. Twelve rectangles. To prove it is the smallest requires logic rather than my brute-force computer approach, since without some logical deductions I would have to search arbitrarily large squares with a huge list of sets of 11 or fewer rectangles which have the correct area.
If the posted image which appeared to be a plain white square gave the answer then this is either superfluous or not optimal.

NB the smallest rectangle which is tiny has a '1' in it which divides it two neatly, don't mistake it for two small rectangles...

> [image]

Comment: I initially didn't see that small rectangle as 1x3 with a 1 in it, I saw it as two small rectangles too small to put a number in. Rotating the picture 90 degrees might make it slightly more presentable.

Comment: Yeah I struggled with that. I'll just add a comment in the description...

Answer (score 6):

With a little research I found...

> ... a solution with 23 rectangles.
>
>  The numbers are the lengths of the short, horizontal, sides. Vertical sides are, of course, three times as long.
>
>  I don't know if this is optimal. I think there could be a solution with fewer rectangles that uses both orientations - i.e. 1x3 and 3x1 rectangles.
>
>  Credit: I adapted my image from a 1x2 rectangle dissection found at [squaring.net](http://www.squaring.net/history_theory/b_trial.html)
>
>
>   [image]

Method

> I looked for a perfect square dissection tiling a 1x2 rectangle, then added another square on the end to make a 1x3 rectangle and stretched this to a square, thus stretching all the original sub-squares to be 1x3 rectangles.

Comment: This is very near to the optimal solution but not it!

Answer (score 4):

***Partial answer***

---

A rectangle of dimensions $k\times3k$ has area $3k^2$. So first we need to solve the following sub-problem:

> Find distinct natural numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and $N$ such that $3(a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2)=N^2$.

Every square is congruent to either 0 or 1 modulo 3. So in order that $a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2$ is a multiple of 3, **the number of $a_n$ which are *not* multiples of 3 must itself be a multiple of 3.**

Every square is congruent to either 0, 1, or 4 modulo 8. So in order that $3(a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2)$ is a square modulo 8, **the number of odd $a_n$ must be congruent to 0, 3, or 4 modulo 8.**

I found one solution: $n=4,a_1=1,a_2=3,a_3=4,a_4=7$, giving $(1\times3)+(3\times9)+(4\times12)+(7\times21)=15^2$. Unfortunately, we can't fit a $7\times21$ rectangle into a $15\times15$ square, so this won't solve the main problem.

Comment: I think it's relevant to specify that N is a multiple of 3 since N^2 is one. This can help.

Comment: I wrote some code to find sets of N kx3k rectangles that sum to a square S*S. Turns out that it's 'open ended' in the sense that you need to search arbitrarily large k even for small N. So this is never going to be trivial. If I limit it to k=75 it makes good progress, nothing below N=8. I also started my tiling program searching small S with all k that will fit, it's searching S=62 now, there's nothing smaller.

Comment: I fixed a bug in my program that finds sets of rectangles. There are *lots* of rectangle sets to consider, so my tiling program is not just wasting CPU cycles. And there are plenty of sets with even as few as 4 rectangles, although you need quite a bit more than four to tile a square.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard to find a (most likely suboptimal) solution with

> 65

rectangles, by combining several solutions to the

> [squaring the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square)

problem. Unfortunately, the resulting square has an edge size of

> 856240

meaning it won't be easy to draw a pixel-perfect image of it. However, we can draw each part separately and then combine them using image magic. The result is here (each rectangle contains two numbers - the size within each part and the size within the whole solution):

> [image: 65]
>  The smallest rectangle is blue-1x1 (6160x18480) and the largest rectangle is blue-80x80 (492800x1478400)

To see why there aren't duplicate rectangles across parts, we note that

> the edge sizes are *almost* mutually coprime, meaning that the only the full squares would scale up to the same size. The "almost" part refers to the first two squares having a GCD of 2, which allows an additional collision - 56x56 from the first part would scale up to the same size as 55x55 from the second part. Neither exists in their respective pairs.

The parts are:

> 112A AJD 1978 from http://squaring.net/sq/ss/spss/o21/spsso21.pdf
>  110A AJD 1978 from http://squaring.net/sq/ss/spss/o22/spsso22.pdf
>  139A AJD 1990 from http://squaring.net/sq/ss/spss/o22/spsso22.pdf
>  The integer in name refers to the edge size. The number of rectangles is in the URL.
>  See also the references section in http://squaring.net/sq/ss/spss/spss.html

Comment: Keep trying. +1 for the effort and time though.

Answer (score 1):

Is this any good? Don't know if it's pixel perfect but it looks cool either way.

> [image: 3:1 in square]

Comment: It seems your third-largest square has dimensions of 149*448, which is not quite 1:3. Deduced from total picture size which is 576x576 pixels.

Comment: @Lolgast Maybe this can be done in the same pattern but with a different image size.

Comment: If I did my calculations correctly, if all those rectangles had a 1x3 ratio, then the whole figure would be 3783 by 3781 (i.e. very slightly wider than it is high).

Comment: @Rick I've just checked it, starting from the smallest rectangle (being 243*729 for integer sizes), but you get a "square" size of 3783*3781. VERY close, but not quite unfortunately.

Comment: This is even lower than the optimal solution :p