# Another geometrical puzzle!

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, visual, geometry

After the mind-boggling **[Dissecting Square](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58646/dissect-a-square-into-31-rectangles)** puzzle, here is yet another geometrical puzzle. But a lot easier.

> In the figure $AE = 111$ and other lengths are unknown. What is the
>   value of $AB^2 + BC^2 + CD^2 + DE^2?$

[image: Figure]

```
Most elegant solution will be accepted. Cheers.
```

Comment: The top voted answer in the no-math-textbook meta question explicitly allows for math problems that have a clever or elegant, puzzlingly-type solution. Since this puzzle is very easily solved by basic geometry, I’m very interested in seeing some creative solutions, especially the one OP had in mind. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Bass, I agree.

Comment: I disagree.  The "obvious" solution is the simplest one, and the chance of a more rational chain of thought is exceedingly low.  In other words, this is not a complicated enough "puzzle" to have the freedom of multiple instructive solutions.

Answer (score 10):

By pythagorean principle,

> $AB^2 + BC^2 + CD^2 + DE^2$
>  $= AC^2 + CD^2 + DE^2$
>  $= AD^2 + DE^2$
>  $= AE^2$
>  $= 111^2 = 12321$

Answer (score 3):

Answer is

> 12321, the square of 111.

---

> Logic: Applying the Pythagorean theorem on the right-angled triangles, we get to know that
>
>  $AB^2 + BC^2 = AC^2$
>  $AC^2 + CD^2 = AD^2$
>  $AD^2 + DE^2 = AE^2$

---

> Substituting the right hand side of the above set of equations (one after the other) in the the sum $AB^2 + BC^2 + CD^2 + DE^2$, and using associativity of addition, we get: 
>  
>  $AB^2 + BC^2 + CD^2 + DE^2 = (((AB^2 + BC^2) + CD^2) + DE^2) = (AC^2 + CD^2) + DE^2 = AD^2 + DE^2 = AE^2$
>  
>  Finally by substituting the value of the length of AE, 111, we get the answer 12321.

Answer (score 2):

Solving with **pythagorean theorem**:

\begin{align}
111^2=&    & &    & &AD^2&+&DE^2\\
     =&    & &AC^2&+&CD^2&+&DE^2\\
     =&AB^2&+&BC^2&+&CD^2&+&DE^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For any two points, you can replace the line segment between them with a path consisting of any two connected perpendicular line segments, and the sum of squares of the segments will not change. (Pythagoras' theorem.)

The diagram shows three such replacements, starting with $AE \xrightarrow{} AD+DE$, followed by  $AD \xrightarrow{} AC+CD$ and  $AC \xrightarrow{} AB+BC$.

Since $AE^2=12321$, and $AB^2+BC^2+CD^2+DE^2 $ is the resulting sum of squares after the three replacements, $AB^2+BC^2+CD^2+DE^2$ must equal $12321$.